# Match everything except tab character

Tags: python, regex

So, I'm trying to parse files with lines that looks as follows:

```
FIB cum + coni, 3x  toen, omdat, hoewel
```

I want to parse these with a regex that looks something like this:

```
r"^FIB\t()\t()$"
```

where the first () matches "cum + coni, 3x" and the second () matches "toen, omdat, hoewel"

to do something like this, I think I need to match everything that's not a tab character or a newline character in the braces, so basically my question boils down to:

Using the python re module, what regular expression will match everything except tab and newline?

Comment: negated character class: `[^\t\n]+`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't actually work

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj : The expected output is the 2 groups stated on line 5. But it'd be nice to see a raw version of the input so we know where the tabs are...

Comment: Sorry tried to edit my comment but for some reason it didn't work
it actually works well, I just made a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
^FIB\s*(.*?)(?<=\s)\s(.*)$
```

You can try this.This gives the required groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/7

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is not a tab `\t` or a newline `\n` is `[^\t\n]`, so your regex becomes:

```
r"^FIB\t([^\t\n]+)\t([^\t\n]+)$"
```

I have added a `+` after the character class to allow multiple character that is not tab or newline.

You can replace `\n` with `\r` or `\r\n` depending on your platfrom.